# Redux state change causes unwanted re render when using custom route (react-router v6)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, redux-thunk

I'm using a simple custom privateRoute to try and block non-users from accessing the route. whenever I update my redux store state, I get a re-render.

EDIT 2: This update only happens if my main component (Users) is nested inside the custom route. also, the unwanted re-render, is in the form component. it has no dependency in the changing state, other than being a sibling of the list component.

Here's the custom route:

```
  const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
    console.log('loggedInUser in privateRoute', loggedInUser);
    //checking this isnt changing to null or undefined at some point. it does not.
    const checkUser = !!loggedInUser
    return checkUser ? children : <Navigate to="/:landing-page" />;
  }
```

loggedInUser is a piece of state, but it is not the problem, since even after removing it, the same problem occurs.
I've tried to simplify it as much as I can, just to see where the problem is, like so:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
    return children
  };
```

my Router (simplified):

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/search-users' element={<PrivateRoute><Users /></PrivateRoute>} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

If I remove said custom route from the Route element, there is no re-render!

'Users' contains two components:

**Form Component**
EDIT: added the component

```
export const UsersSearchForm = React.memo(() => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  let debounce;
  const { handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (ev) => {
    const filterTerm = ev.target.value;
    if (debounce) clearTimeout(debounce);
    if (!filterTerm.length) return;
    debounce = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('dispatch!');
      dispatch(getUsers(filterTerm));
    }, 700);
  };
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        id="filter"
        onChange={(ev) => handleSubmit(onSubmit(ev))}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search for new friends..."
        autoComplete="off"
      />
    </form>
  );
});
```

a form with one text input, to dispatch the user search action. using useDispatch (with a debouncer), which sends the action and updates the store (sets 'filteredUsers' to the response) when there's a response. without this update, there is obviously no re-render.

**List Component**

a list component where I map over the results to display them. Mapping over the users by grabbing users from the store using useSelector.

**THE PROBLEM**

The form value is resetting with every search since the component re-renders.

here is my (simplified) store-reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
filteredUsers: [],
}

export function userReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
case 'GET_USERS':
      return {
        ...state,
        filteredUsers: action.users
      }
default:
      return state
  }
}
```

store-action function:

```
export const getUsers = (filter) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            const users = await httpService.get(`user/search/${filter}`)
            dispatch({ type: 'GET_USERS', users })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('getUsers error:', err);
        }
    }
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: What is `loggedInUser` in the `PrivateRoute` component? I also don't follow what you think is an issue. If you are updating state that is being used either by the `PrivateRoute` or `User` component then a rerender will, and should, be triggered. Can you clarify what you call "PROBLEM" with the form value is resetting? What specific form value is resetting? Something in `UsersSearchForm`? Please share how `UsersSearchForm` is used and rendered.

Comment: loggedInUser is is also a part of the redux state. i separated the form and the list components in hope the form wont re-render. why would it? only his siblings state is updating, not him. 

but, the problem is deeper than that. as i mentioned - even if i take loggedInUser out of the question - the same re-render happens. i can prevent this re-render when i use a standard Route, with no custom route - then redux only updates the relevant component, as expected.

Comment: Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 0):

You have not value in input:

```
    <form>
        <input
        id="filter"
        onChange={(ev) => handleSubmit(onSubmit(ev))}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search for new friends..."
        autoComplete="off"
        value={your_input_value_from_state}
      />
   </form>
```

Comment: there's no need for a value. thanks for trying.